# Continued Fractions periodicity and convolution.

Tags: continued-fractions

Continued fractions for rationals terminate, for transcendentals like pi, they do not terminate and for irrationals (but non transcendentals) they repeat -- is this correct?

Comment: Are you referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#The_equivalence_transformation ?

Comment: you should ask the bit about convolution as a separate question

Comment: Well, okay, since I liked your answer for the first part so much but you didn't talk about the second part I will take your suggestion and ask again. Also that wiki link is fascinating but not exactly what I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know all simple continued fractions converge so if a continued fraction was periodic (period 4 for illustration) with value $x$ we could write $$x = a_0 + \cfrac{1}{a_1 + \cfrac{1}{a_2+ \cfrac{1}{a_3 + \cfrac{1}{x}}}}.$$

Each part of a continued fraction maps $\frac{p}{q} \mapsto a_i + \frac{1}{(\tfrac{p}{q})} = \frac{q + a_i p}{p}$ so apply this iteration to get $$x =  \frac{1 + a_2 a_3 + a_0 a_3 + a_0 a_1 + a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3 + (a_2 + a_0 (a_1 a_2 + 1)) x}{a_3 + a_1 + a_1 a_2 a_3 + (a_1 a_2 + 1) x}$$ it is instructive to perform this iteration by hand. The key thing to notice is we have a form $\frac{A + xB}{C + xD}$ where $A,B,C,D$ are integers.

**Theorem** The continued fraction transform preserves the form $\frac{A + xB}{C + xD}$.
*proof*: $$\frac{A + xB}{C + xD} \mapsto \frac{(C + a_i A) + x (a_i B + D)}{A + xB}.$$

From this we can deduce that all periodic continued fractions are quadratic irrationals: if $x = \frac{A + xB}{C + xD}$ then $x^2 D + x (C - B) - A = 0$ therefore (by the quadratic formula) $x$ is a quadratic irrational.

---

Yes, A continued fraction is finite if and only if the number is rational. This follows from the fact that a continued fraction gives infinitely many excellent rational approximations of the number and rationals only have finitely many such approximations (See [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) for more on this).

The periodic continued fractions are exactly the quadratic irrationals: numbers of the form $\frac{A + \sqrt{B}}{C}$. The converse (that every quadratic irrational has a periodic continued fraction) is more involved.

So the pattern of cubic irrationals - which are not transcendental - doesn't have any periodic pattern (and I am not sure if any patterns are known at all).

Answer (score 1):

That is not correct.  Continued fractions for *quadratic* irrationals repeat.  But for higher-degree irrationals, such as $\sqrt[3]2$, the continued fraction does not repeat.

I am not aware of any research into the particular convolution operation you mention, but that doesn't mean there is none.

Comment: Okay I see the proof below. Thanks.