# Are all numbers that have a non-repeating, non-terminating continued fraction sequence transcendental?

Tags: continued-fractions

(By continued fraction sequence, I'm specifically talking about the one kind where the numerator of every fraction is 1.)

As a kid in middle school, I learned that all irrational numbers have non-repeating, non-terminating positional notation (o.k.a. "decimal") expansions.

However, as a kid in first-year university, I learned that some irrational algebraic numbers have repeating continued fraction expansions (and, of course, that all rationals have a finite continued fraction expansion). So my question now is, do *all* algebraic numbers have a repeating continued fraction expansion? Are there some transcendentals that have a repeating expansion, or algebraic numbers that have a non-repeating expansion?

Comment: See here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeriodicContinuedFraction.html or here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_irrational

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, continued faction expansions repeat only for the so-called "[quadratic irrationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_irrational)", numbers $x$ satisfying $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ for some integers $a, b$ and $c$.  In particular, the continued fraction expansion for the algebraic number $\sqrt[3]2$ does not repeat.

[Continued Fractions periodicity and convolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/298065) on this site has a proof.